# finds two numbers in an array with the smallest distance to each other In Java

Tags: java, arrays

One question from a website: Implement a Java function that finds two numbers in an array with the smallest distance to each other. The function should return the index of the first number.

Here is my thoughts. But I don't know how to implement it.

1. Step1. Get all the result of 2 element arrays from a given array.
   For example {4,5,7,11} have 4*3 = 12 two element arrays.
2. Step2. Calculate each the two array distance. And find out the minimum
   distance.

I do viewed at least 10 google results. Seems don't have the good answer. IN real life, people would first sort it then try some way to figure it out. But let's assume the array as it is. We do not sort it.
The following code is based on one expert's answer. But unfortunately it seems not working...

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class TestallBasics1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{2,1,6,8,10,89,54};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        int difference=0;
        int n = arr.length;
        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
            if(difference > (arr[i+1]-arr[i]))
            {difference = arr[i+1]-arr[i];}

        System.out.println(difference);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorting the array might be an option so I wouldn't dismiss out of hand. After all "how people would normally do it" often is a good starting point. One thing that I miss: how is distance defined? Numeric difference? Positional distance, i.e. by index?

Comment: If you are not allowed to modify the array, you may make a copy and sort the copy. Your approach without sorting is not the most efficient, but can work, so you may also go ahead with it.

Comment: @Thomas. Here let's assume all is positive integer. The distance is the larger subtract the smaller.

Comment: OK, so it's the numeric difference then. In that case I would build an array of elements that contain the value as well as the original index, sort by value in descending order and iterate over the array comparing adjacent elements (basically `a[i] - a[i+1]`)  and keep track of the pair that produced the smallest difference (you probably could stop once you get a result of 0). You could then extract the values and indices in the original array from that pair.

Comment: Btw, your code would already print the smallest difference which would be 1 for the elements 2 and 1. There's one slight error though: you initialize `difference` to 0 which is already as small as it can get. Instead initialize it with the highest value possible, i.e. `int difference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`. That way the first real difference will be smaller in any case.

Comment: The smallest difference between neighbor items or between any items?

Comment: @Thomas I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer online. Brillant!

```
public int getIndexOfMinimumDistance() {
    int index = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[]{999,0,5,8,10,89,54};

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
        if ( Math.abs( numbers[index] - numbers[index + 1]) >
            Math.abs( numbers[i] - numbers[i + 1])) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

step1: sort the array by applying any technique or using any predefined methods.
`Arrays.sort()`, `Collections.sort` etc. which is applicable.
step2: Iterate the elements and find the difference between the current and next element, store the difference in a variable and update it when the difference is smaller than the current.

```
int difference=0;
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
    if(difference > (arr[i+1]-arr[i])){
        difference = arr[i+1]-arr[i];
    }
}
```

now you will have the smallest distance in `difference` variable.

Comment: `The function should return the index of the first number`